# JNA or System.loadLibrary?

Tags: java, c++, jna

I've got a .dll that was compiled for x64(same as my current java install) in VS2013 with this source(c++):

```
namespace jdlltest
{
    int aconst()
    {
        return 108;
    }
}
```

now I'm trying to load it using JNA like this:

```
interface jdll extends Library
{
    jdll inst=(jdll)Native.loadLibrary("jdll",jdll.class);
    int aconst();
}
```

I'm getting the method not found error, even if I try to move the function outside the namespace. I've also tried using the System.loadLibrary() function but I've got no idea how it works, since there's little or no explanation at all, so this was my attempt:

```
public class Main
{
    public native int aconst();

    public static void main(String[] string)
    {
        System.loadLibrary("jdll");
        new Main().aconst();
    }
}
```

again this was done when the function wasn't in a namespace, it didn't work with similar error. Since I'm new to this I got multiple questions:

- How do I get this to work?
- How do I call functions from namespace?
- Which of the two ways is better and in what case?
- Could I use a c++ class from java?

Comment: JNA and JNI are two completely different things so you are asking two questions at once. For JNI see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615 for JNA see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wf2w9f6x.aspx

Comment: thanks for that, extern "C" fixed it :D